# Reading JSON feed of external HTTPS site

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Is it possible to read JSON feed available in another site which is HTTPS?
I'm getting empty string in return.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but we don't have enough information. Perhaps your HTTPS client is rejecting the server's certificate, or maybe the same-origin policy is obstructing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible as long as you respect the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). For cross domain AJAX you could use [JSON/P](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) or if you don't have control over the distant domain and it doesn't expose a `JSON/P` data you might need to setup a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between both domains.

Answer (score 0):

You also want to check out CORS

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/